# Batch file runs in some folder and not others

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

Final update: I have determined code that works in all folders, even those with lots of parentheses.  It is as follows:

```
FOR %%# IN ("*.flac") DO (Title %~nx0 Processing: %%~nx# 
            ffmpeg -i "%%~nx#" -ab 192k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 "%%~n#.mp3"
            IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 IF EXIST "%%~nx#" DEL /q "%%~nx#")

ECHO Completed %~nx0

PAUSE
```

The reason for the failure was a combination of parentheses in the folder names and hyphens in the filenames.  The most important part of the final code is the double quotes.  This resolved the problem with hyphens in the filename.  It turned out to not be necessary to have `cd /D "%~dp0."` as the first line, so I removed it from the code.  Thank you to everyone for all of your suggestions.  I really appreciate the help and I am glad this was completely resolved.

History Starts here:

After all of the suggestions, here is the code to run in the folder of flac files:

```
cd /D "%~dp0."

FOR %%# IN ("*.flac") DO (Title %~nx0 Processing: %%~nx#
                ffmpeg -i "%%~nx#" -ab 192k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 "%%~n#.mp3")
                    
ECHO Completed %~nx0
PAUSE
```

Here are my current troubleshooting steps as completed:

I renamed the files in one of the folders in which it does not run to "a.flac", "b.flac", "c.flac", etc.  That is to make sure it is not a filename related problem.  It did not run.

I renamed the folder itself to a single letter to make sure it was not a folder name issue (`F:\MUSIC\j`).  It did not run.

I copied the entire folder and gave it a new single-letter name (`F:\MUSIC\y`).  It did not run.

I copied the files to a newly-created single-letter named folder at the same directory level (`F:\MUSIC\d`).  It did not work.

I copied the flac files and bat file from the single-letter folder to a newly created single-letter folder. It did not run.

So, I went back the original folder and RENAMED MY .bat FILE from `single folder - flac to 192.bat` to `192.bat`.  It ran perfectly.

I went back and renamed the .bat file in all folders described above.  They all ran perfectly.

Next, I renamed my master .bat file to `single_folder_flac_to_192.bat`.  I ran it in the original file folder with all of the original names for folder and files.  It ran perfectly.

I then copied it into each of the folder described above.  It ran perfectly.

I then went back to my original code and renamed it to `192a.bat`.  This still did not run in the original folder, but ran perfectly in the others I created.

So, I renamed my original folder from `F:\MUSIC\Yanni - Live At The Acropolis (1994) [FLAC]` to `ylata`.  It did not run.

That is all I have time for before needing to go to work.  More at lunch time.

Original Post Starts Here:

I am using Windows 10 Pro on my home PC.

I have a batch file which uses ffmpeg to create mp3 from flac and then delete the flac.  It runs perfectly in most folders of music. The code is here:

```
FOR %%a IN ("*.flac") DO (Title %~0 Processing: %%~na.flac
            ffmpeg -i "%%~na.flac" -ab 192k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 "%%~na.mp3"
            if not errorlevel 1 if exist "%%~pna.flac" del /q "%%~pna.flac")
ECHO Completed %~n0
PAUSE
```

In some folders, when I run the batch, it just blinks and goes away.  Yes- there are flac files in the folders.

I have checked the different music folders for their properties (read only, access, etc.) and they look identical.  The file names are "normal".  It doesn't matter which drive I copy the folder into, the results are the same.

I have run the file as Administrator and get the same result.

What else should I be looking into?

Comment: I'd presume that your issue lies with this line `FOR %%a IN ("*.flac") DO (Title %~0 Processing: %%~na.flac`. My presumption is that it occurs when file names include some poison characters. In your example it has closing parentheses, so the line will now look like this, `FOR %%a IN ("*.flac") DO (Title %~0 Processing: Yanni - Live At The Acropolis (1994) [FLAC].flac` and that inner closing parenthesis is prematurely closing the `DO` portion of your loop.

Comment: As Compo suggests probably an issue with that 1st unwrapped `for` variable try `FOR %%a IN ("*.flac") DO (Title %~0 Processing: "%%~na.flac"
            ffmpeg -i "%%~na.flac" -ab 192k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 "%%~na.mp3"
            if not errorlevel 1 if exist "%%~pna.flac" del /q "%%~pna.flac")
ECHO Completed %~n0
PAUSE`

Comment: Please do not [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64723855) the same question! Edit the original one and give it some time ti become reopened – given you provided sufficient information, of course…